# Discrete Math -- Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am struggling with thinking about this. Any help would be great!!

A medical research survey categorizes adults as follows:

- by gender (male or female)
- by age group (age groups are 18-25, 26-35, 36-50, 51+)
- by income (less than 30k/year, 30k-60k/year, more than 60k/year)
- for women only: by whether they have been pregnant (yes/no)
- for men only: by frequency of undergoing prostate exams (frequently, rarely, never).

What minimum size of a set of adults will guarantee that there are two people in it with matching characteristics in all categories? You do not need to explain your answer.

Comment: How many different categories are there? Have you heard of the pidgeonhole principle?

Comment: I have heard of it, but I think the way the problem is laid out might be why I can't seem to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Based on this

[image: PowerPoint Lecture Video for Discrete Math]

I believe you would have (choices)

- (5)

  Woman : Yes

  Woman : No

  Male  : Frequently

  Male  : Rarely

  Male  : Never
- (4) by age group (age groups are 18-25, 26-35, 36-50, 51+)
- (3) by income (less than 30k/year, 30k-60k/year, more than 60k/year)

$$5*4*3=60$$

By the product rule, there are 60 ways of answering this survey. Therefore if,

$$60+1=61$$

61 people were surveyed, two will have matching characteristics.

Answer (score -2):

By the Pigeonhole Principle it would be one more than the number of categories, C(5,2)*4*3 = 10*4*3 = 120 => 120 +1 = 121.

Comment: There are actually 5*4*3 categories, so the right answer is 60+1.